# SQL: how to select last purchased product per client?

Tags: sql, mysql

Consider the following tables structure:

- `invoice`: id, client_id
- `items`: id, invoice_id, name, date

My goal is to get the following dataset: `client_id, name, date` but the name and date are the columns that correspond to the last purchased product.

I tried the following query, but it does not produce the correct result

```
SELECT 
    i.client_id, ii.name, MAX(ii.date) 
FROM
    invoice i
INNER JOIN
    invoice_item ii ON i.id = ii.invoice_id
GROUP BY
    i.client_id;
```

Comment: Why do you have `i` as the alias for both the `invoice` table and the `items` table?

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan sorry, fixed that

Comment: Oh ok, I see. The issue is probably that you are selecting the max date for each client without considering that the item associated with the date might not be the one selected by the `ii.name` column. You can probably fix this with a subquery. Do you want me to show an example in an "Answer" post?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention what RDBMS you're using - if it does support CTE's (Common Table Expressions) and windowing functions (many of the most used RDBMS do support it), you could use something like this:

```
WITH Purchases AS
(
    SELECT 
        i.client_id, ii.name, ii.date,
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.client_id ORDER BY ii.date DESC)
    FROM
        invoice i
    INNER JOIN
        invoice_item ii ON i.id = ii.invoice_id
)
SELECT
    p.client_id, p.name, p.date
FROM
    Purchases
WHERE
    p.RowNum = 1;
```

The `Purchases` is a CTE - sort of an "one-off, inline view"; using the `ROW_NUMBER` function, you "partition" your data by `client_id`, and all purchases for each client are sequentially numbered, ordered descendingly by purchase date - so the most recent purchase for each client will always have `RowNum = 1` - and that's exactly what I select from that CTE.